# Chrome is reporting page is unsecure with mixed content for data:image/png;base64

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

Chrome is reporting that I have mixed content when serving up a page over HTTPS in my MVC project. I have tracked it down to the following CSS rule:

```
select option:checked, select option:hover {
    background: #3399ff url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAEAQMAAACTPww9AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAABlBMVEUylfj///+2X69TAAAAAWJLR0QB/wIt3gAAAAtJREFUCNdjYIAAAAAIAAEvIN0xAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC") repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

and in particular the **data:image/png;base64** embedded image. If I take that out then the page passes.

I would still like to keep the CSS as is, but what do I need to change it to so that it serves it up using HTTPS? As the underlying CSS is being served up via HTTPS I cannot see that I would need to change the background property declaration?

Comment: looks like you just need to adjust the link to the image. Can you add a direct link to the image such as "/image/example.png"  ?

Comment: I would prefer not to add a direct link to the image but rather keep on using the base64 approach. CSS is managed by designers and they don't have rights to upload images to server in this case.